# Find and replace in R

Tags: r, replace

In the following example, how can I replace those instances when `italic(P) == 0` with `italic(P) < 0.001`?

```
df <- structure(list(STRING = c("italic(R)^2 == 0.15 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", "italic(R)^2 == 0 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", 
"italic(R)^2 == 0.17 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", "italic(R)^2 == 0.15 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", 
"italic(R)^2 == 0 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", "italic(R)^2 == 0.07 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0.002", 
"italic(R)^2 == 0.12 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", "italic(R)^2 == 0.11 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0", 
"italic(R)^2 == 0.06 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0.006", "italic(R)^2 == 0.08 * \",\" ~ italic(P) == 0.001"
)), .Names = c("STRING"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried `gsub("== 0", "< 0.001", df$STRING)` but that is obviously wrong since it will replace also all the other instances were the pattern is found. I only want to replace those that are `0` and not `0.`

I can manually change it with within `fix(df)` popup window but that is not good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost had it. Putting `$` at the end of the expression matches only those strings where `== 0` occur at the end of the string.

```
gsub("== 0$", "< 0.001", df$STRING)
```

This assumes that `== 0` actually does occur only at the end (as in your example). If it occurs also "mid-string", then more complex expressions can be found. However, I think that cleaning up those character strings and working with `"== 0$"` is the cleaner solution.

EDIT:

Acommodating more complicated strings requires more complicated expressions. As per your updated question, the simplest solution I can think of is:

```
gsub("== 0( |$)", "< 0.001\\1", df$STRING)
```

This assumes that each match is either followed by a space or the end of the string. `()` is a grouping, `\\1` is a backreference to that group. Please also have a look at the answer by @hwnd who has another solution.

Comment: That's it! But what if there are instances where `italic(R)^2 == 0` and I also want it to be `italic(R)^2 < 0.001`? What would be more complex expressions? **NOTE**: I edited my example to include such instances.

Comment: I upvoted your answer even though it was a late reply to OP's comment, you still edited your answer with an updated solution after I answered. Most users don't tend to do that.

Comment: Thanks @SimonG! Great answer!

Comment: I think having two answers for this question is acceptable because they are not completely redundant (albeit similar). Someone else might even have a more flexible or efficient solution based on one of the two. I try to tend to my posts whenever I can.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you would need to modify your regular expression:

```
gsub('== 0(?=\\h|$)', '< 0.001', df$STRING, perl=TRUE)
```

[**CodeBunk**](http://codebunk.com/pb/53155760)

Comment: Holy smokes, that's a mouthful! I will sit down and try to digest it. Since @SimonG answered my initial question and it works for me in my particular case, I accepted his answer, but at the same time up-voted yours, too. Thanks for this!

Comment: Awesome :D! Thanks @hwnd